# Cannot Retrieve the Address of a Broken TCP/IP connection by socket.getpeername() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp

I run a TCP server by select.select monitor and keep a dynamic address book by connection IP address. Whenever a connection breaks, the server will retrieve the IP address on the other side by function "socket.getpeername()" and deleted corresponding entry from dynamic address book.

Generally this works fine. "**socket.getpeername()**" will always tell the address of the other side in the **broken connection**. But **sometimes it fails** - and windows says the socket has been broken so that "socket.getpeername()" cannot work!

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQFYF.png)

I send the catched broken socket to sub thread to handle it, and sub thread find the socket itself is broken and cannot use the getpeername() otherwise WinError10038

The Main Thread catches the broken socket in select reading:

```
read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(active_socks,[],[],TIMEOUT)
for sock in read_sockets:
......
    except:
        mailbox.put( (("sock_err",sock), 'localhost') )
```

The last step is to put the broken socket object "sock" in to a queue "mailbox". 
Then the sub thread receives this message from "mailbox" and tries to do something to the socket object “sock” and getpeername() goes wrong **sometimes**：

```
print(sock)>>>
<socket.socket [closed] fd=-1, family=AFNET, type=SOCKSTREAM, proto=0>
sock.getpeername()>>>
OS.Error[WinError10038]an operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

Comment: Your socket is closed. So it can't get the IP address.

Comment: thanks for reply. But is there another way to tell the IP address that the socket [was] connected to?

Comment: Don't know if it is useful: [pyroute2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyroute2) can show IP routes…